How can I use online bible resources to find a word in the Septuagint, and the Hebrew word it aligns with?
I've recently come to understand that the Septuagint is the Old Testament translated into Greek.
This is an important discovery to me, as I now have the potential to see which Greek words are used to translate Hebrew words, and how this compares to the use of these words in the New Testament.
I'm currently using the "Septuagint" tab of the Blue Letter Bible "Interlinear" section.

However, it does not tell me which Greek word aligns with which Hebrew word (or which English word in the translation).
I can surmise by looking at the meanings of the Greek words and determining which words in the Hebrew translation they line up with, but I'd prefer to have a more accurate method.
Are there any resources available to me?

this is a great question, but it's not a hermeneutics question

Oh I see. Thank you @AviAvraham

@AviAvraham "Hermeneutics is the theory and methodology of text interpretation" - Wikipedia.  Luke has a procedure for performing exegesis. Isn't that hermeneutics? Hermeneutics should be more than studying the procedures of dead people. And if his procedure is hermeneutics, shouldn't finding resources to implement that methodology also be hermeneutics? I'm not trying to be picky, I'm trying to determine if my methodology for exegesis is hermeneutics.

yes, @HallLivingston, I did wonder the same thing when I looked up the meaning of hermeneutics.

The MySword app has an Apostolic Bible Polygot (ABP) Bible. This is an interlinear Old and New Testament. The OT is not exactly the same as the LXX, but the differences, for the most part, are slight. When the two disagree you need to compare and consider the differences. Even where they do not agree there is an advantage of working from an English\Greek Interlinear to isolate differences.

I bought a Septuagint Interlinear in hopes of doing the same thing. To my disappointment it was Greek/English rather then Greek/Hebrew.
Here is a similar question with an answer.

Critical Edition of Septuagint in Hebrew


Thank you @Hall Livingston. The resource they mention seems to be difficult to interpret, but at least I know there is a resource I can learn to use.

In applying the principles of hermeneutics, I frequently refer to interlinear Hebrew for the Masoretic text (https://biblehub.com/interlinear/), The Dead Sea Scrolls Bible by Abegg, Flint, & Ulrich, and the Apostolic Bible Polyglot (https://www.apostolicbible.com/) for the Greek Septuagint and the New Testament Greek interlinear.

It's important to note that the Septuagint is a "snapshot in time" of the Tanakh based on a manuscript that predated the Masoretic text and its recensions.
Also note that the translation of text from any language to another language can be very challenging, especially when dealing with idioms and nuances.
Translations from Hebrew of Greek are on a scale between word-for-word literal translations at on extreme and thought-for-thought paraphrases at the other. Which is better is a matter of controversy and depends on the text in consideration.
R.P Nettelhorst, in an article in the Jerusalem Post on July 14, 2015, The Textual Criticism of the Bible, wrote the following:


It is important to realize – and most people who have not learned a
second language wouldn't know – that there is no such thing as a
one-to-one correspondence between languages. You cannot have a word
for word translation that is at all readable, because the word order
is different, the nature of the grammar is different and even the
sense of a word may cover a wider or smaller range than the
corresponding English word.

For example, in English we use the word, "love" in sentences such as "I love my wife" and "I love my mother." In Greek, several different words are used to specify different types of love, including agapé, philos, storgḗ, etc. These distinctions are usually lost when translating these words into English. The word translated "love" in John 21 is a famous example.
Hope this helps.
